# How to install Snow Leopard from USB where USB disk is prepared using Linux?

Tags: snow-leopard, startup, usb, bootable-disk

I'm trying to install Snow Leopard (a retail version) into my MacBook, but seems like that the MacBook can't find the boot disk over USB.

I guess this is related to the fact that I mounted the .iso of Snow Leopard via Linux, using `dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdx` and this rewrites the boot sector.

Is there a way to copy the ISO into my USB disk via Linux and make the MacBook recognize this?

Comment: I know nothing about Linux, what is the partition map of your USB drive? It needs to be GPT (GUID)

Comment: I partitioned my USB via Disk Utility, and set the map to GUID type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use Linux for this? Just do it in OS X. To prepare the USB drive (e.g. 8-GB flash drive), you need to partition it using the **GUID scheme** and format it to the file system standard **'Macintosh Extended (Journaled)'**, also known as 'HFS+ (Journaled)'.

Then use Disk Utility's **Restore** feature to copy the contents of the iso image file *(Source)* to the USB drive *(Destination)*. When done, restart the Mac keeping the **Option key** pressed – the USB drive should then show up in the boot volume lineup...

There are many tutorials for this process on the Internet, e.g., http://www.maciverse.com/install-os-x-snow-leopard-from-usb-flash-drive.html